# LINQ select new error. Not able to access list

Tags: c#, linq

my Linq query is.

```
string spouseName="jenny";
var empData = from sData in EmpList
              from member in sData.familyNames
              where string.Compare(member, spouseName, true) == 0
              select new Employee
              {
                  CompanyDept = sData.company,
                  EmpName = sData.empName,
                  FamilyNames.Add(spouse)   //ERROR HERE Not able to access as list
              };
```

Here empList is `List<Employee>`

```
class Employee
{
   private string companyDept
   private string empName
   private List<string> _familyNames = new List<string>();

   public string CompanyDept
   {
      get { return companyDept}
      set { companyDept= value; }
   }

   public string EmpName
   {
      get { return empName}
      set { empName= value; }
   }

   public List<string> FamilyNames 
   {
      get { return _familyNames }
      set { _familyNames = value; }
   }
}
```

Question:

Here I am trying to get a linq output as of type `Employee`... but the list familyNames contains only one item spouse name, not list of all family members.??

But I am getting error at familyList. Not able to add items to familyNames List to not able to assign.

Need help, why error is comming or I am wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct translation is:

```
select new Employee
{
    CompanyDept = sData.company,
    EmpName = sData.empName,
    FamilyNames = { spouse } // 'nested' collection-initializer
};
```

The reason is that you only need an `Add` call on `FamilyMember`, not a full property reassignment to a *new* list, which is what `FamilyNames = new List<string> { spouse }` would do.

Loosely speaking, this translates to:

```
var temp = new Employee();
temp.CompanyDept = sData.company;
temp.EmpName = sData.empName;
temp.FamilyNames.Add(spouse);
return temp; // this is selected.
```

Comment: I had no idea you could do this!

Comment: hmm.... this works too. These are 4.0 features. Probably we do assigning new list to Add.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize the list yourself. Change:

```
FamilyNames.Add(spouse)
```

To:

```
FamilyNames = new List<string>(new []{ spouse })
```

Comment: Oh thanx... it worked. But why like that. I mean whenever I create any object of employee, I can directly add to familyNames. But why not in this case.

Comment: @GAPS, that is the way [object initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) work. Basically you cannot access a member property while constructing the object, but you can assign to it.

Comment: @Klause that is true. But when we initilize in normal way we can use the member property also right...

 

**Employee ee = new Employee();  ee.companyDept="xyz"  ee.empName="abc" ee.FamilyName.Add("NameAny")**


This way we can access. Then what happen to my LINQ case

Answer (score 3):

It should be something like

```
select new Employee
{
    CompanyDept = sData.company,
    EmpName = sData.empName,
   // FamilyNames.Add(spouse)   //ERROR HERE Not able to access as list
     FamilyNames = new List<string> {spouse}
} ;
```

Although I would have expected `sData.spouse` or `member.spouse`

Comment: Since the OP only needs an `Add` (and not a full reassignment of the list), make the last line:  `FamilyNames =   { spouse }`

Comment: There is, it's created in the field-initializer.

Comment: @Ani, yes, I missed that. I prefer the `new` inside the `select` myself.

Comment: Fair enough, but they aren't equivalent. Imagine if a) there was no setter - wouldn't compile b) the list were pre-populated in the constructor - different results.